# How to hide delete button in textbox that shows up when you type anything in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I want to remove delete button in textbox that shows up when you type anything in jQuery mobile. When I click reset button textbox is clear but delete button is not hidden.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26Le9/).

html

```
<div id="dvSearch" data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label" data-theme="a">
    <div class="clsNote">Entrer le nom du membre que vous desirez contacter</div>
    <label id="lblSearch" for="txtsearch">Search</label>
    <input type="search" id="txtsearch" data-i18n="[placeholder]attr.placeholderSearch;" data-theme="b" />
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnReset" class="LnkButton ui-icon-alt ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span">
                                        <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                                            <span class="ui-btn-text">Reset</span>
                                        </span>
 </a>
```

jQuery

```
 $('#btnReset').on('click', function (e) {
     // $(".ui-icon-delete").hide();//**this line doesnt work**
     $("#txtsearch").val('');
 });
```

Comment: Could not find element with class ui-icon-delete

Comment: when you type anything in textbox on right side a delete button appears if you inspect it. it will show as <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span> visit jsfiddle link

Comment: you have to options, either to remove that button, or `blur` input when you reset it http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/26Le9/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me after spending couple of hours i figure it out. I programatically clicked the button in jquery

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ne8HU/)

```
  $('#btnReset').on('click', function (e) {
     $(".ui-icon-delete").trigger('click');      
 });
```

for details
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btnReset').on('click', function (e) {
     $(".ui-input-clear").hide();
     $("#txtsearch").val('');
 });

 $('#txtsearch').keyup(function(){
     var content = $('#txtsearch').val();
     if(content != '')
     {
         $(".ui-input-clear").show();
     }
     else
     {
         $(".ui-input-clear").hide();
     }
});
$(".ui-input-clear").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Use this Script.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26Le9/5/)

Comment: it is   permanently removing it when i type anything its not showing again. when i type anything ui-input-clear must show again